# How do I create a regression line with various variables in R

Tags: r, plot, regression, prediction

I have already created the actual regression code but I am trying to get the regression line and a predicted line onto a plot but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
m1 <- lm(variable1 ~ 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8, data = prog)
summary(m1)
```

and then I want to create the plot on the basis of `hyp.data` but I am still a bit lost.

Comment: In general and in base R plotting you can simply do `abline(m1)` after plotting your data. However, how do you plan on visualising your data in 8 dimensions?

Comment: yea, I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to create a line with predictions as well. I am supposed to be taking the `lm(outcome variable ~ treatment+ counfounders1through8)` and then creating 2 lines out of that.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. How do *you* plan on plotting a line with predictions in 8 dimensions? Have a look at a simpler example below.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two (not 7!) predictor variables; one is `numeric`, the other categorical (i.e. a `factor`).

```
# Simulate data
set.seed(2017);
x1 <- 1:10;
x2 <- as.factor(sample(c("treated", "not_treated"), 10, replace = TRUE));
df <- cbind.data.frame(
    y = 2 * x1 + as.numeric(x2) - 1 + rnorm(10),
    x1 = x1,
    x2 = x2);
```

In that case you can do the following:

```
# Fit the linear model    
m1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = df);

# Get predictions
df$pred <- predict(m1);

# Plot data    
library(ggplot2);
ggplot(df, aes(x = x1, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ x2, scales = "free") +
    geom_line(aes(x = x1, y = pred), col = "red");
```

[image]